# RadioButtonFor for a list of objects mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have a Model :

```
public class Period
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string PickerFormat { get; set; }
}
```

and the ViewModel (just involved part):

```
public class ChartsViewModel
{
    public HistoricViewModel HistoricViewModel { get;set;}
}
public class HistoricViewModel
{
    public Period SelectedPeriod { get; set; }       
    public IEnumerable<Period> AllPeriodes { get; set; }       
}
```

In my view, I want to display a list of radio buttons to get the selected `Period` in my Model.

That's what I'm doing :

```
@foreach (Period period in Model.HistoricViewModel.AllPeriodes)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Id, period.Id)
    @period.DisplayText
}
```

At this step, `SelectedPeriod.Id` is well binded to `ChartsViewModel`.
Now, how to bind other properties (`Selected`,`PickerFormat`and `DisplayText`)?

Thanks

EDIT: Full View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Charts Page";
}
@model MultiRetouchesService.ChartsViewModel
@using MultiRetouchesService;

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/charts")


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //DropdownList
        setAllDropdowns();
        //DateTimePicker
        setDateTimePickers();
    });
</script>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
            @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { @id = string.Empty }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "FilterForm", onchange = "DisplayChart()" }))
            {
                <div class="d-flex flex-sm-nowrap flex-md-wrap flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-6 bg-light border border-primary rounded text-dark text-center mt-1">
                        <h5>Dates</h5>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="startingDate">
                                <span class="align-middle my-auto pr-2">Du:</span>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.StartingDate, new { @class = "form-control mt-1" })
                                <div class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text fa fa-calendar mt-1"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="endingDate">
                                <span class="align-middle my-auto pr-2">Au:</span>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.EndingDate, new { @class = "form-control mt-1" })
                                <div class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                                    <span class="input-group-text fa fa-calendar mt-1"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-light border border-primary rounded text-center text-dark  mt-1 ml-sm-1 ml-lg-0 ml-md-0">
                        <h5 class="text-center">Période</h5>

                        @foreach (PeriodViewModel period in Model.HistoricViewModel.AllPeriodes)
                        {
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Id, period.Id)     
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => period.PickerFormat)                                   
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border border-primary rounded text-dark text-center bg-light mt-1">
                    <h5 class="text-center">Filtres</h5>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedVehicules, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllVehicules, new { id = "dropDownVehicules", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedSectors, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllSectors, new { id = "dropDownSectors", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedImputations, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllImputations, new { id = "dropDownImputations", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedMissions, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllMissions, new { id = "dropDownMissions", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedPieces, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllPieces, new { id = "dropDownPieces", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedDefaults, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllDefaults, new { id = "dropDownDefaults", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                        <div class="m-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedLocalizations, Model.HistoricViewModel.AllLocalizations, new { id = "dropDownLocalizations", multiple = "multiple" })</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            <canvas id="barChart" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply continue the code of your foreach:

```
@foreach (Period period in Model.HistoricViewModel.AllPeriodes)
{
  Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Id, period.Id);
  Html.LabelFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.DisplayText);
}
```

Comment: Try it: Html.LabelFor(m => period.DisplayText);

Comment: Post your full view.