# How to bind my model in MVC by HTML code?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC/Web developmnent and I'm facing a big trouble with no answer here:
[RadioButtonFor for a list of objects mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370239/radiobuttonfor-for-a-list-of-objects-mvc)

So, I'm trying to understand.

Considering I have these Model :

```
public class ChartsViewModel
{
    public HistoricViewModel HistoricViewModel { get;set;}
}
public class HistoricViewModel
{
    public PeriodViewModel SelectedPeriod { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PeriodViewModel> AllPeriodes { get; set; } 
}
public class PeriodViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string PickerFormat { get; set; }
}
```

`ChartsViewModel` is the model used in the view.
Now I'm trying to understand the binding and I wrote this hard coded HTML to do that.

```
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_Selected" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Selected" type="hidden" value="True" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_PickerFormat" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.PickerFormat" type="hidden" value="formatA" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_Id" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Id" type="radio" value="1" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_DisplayText" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.DisplayText" type="hidden" value="pariodeA" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_Selected1" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Selected" type="hidden" value="False" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_PickerFormat1" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.PickerFormat" type="hidden" value="formatB" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_Id1" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Id" type="radio" value="2" />
    <input id="HistoricViewModel_SelectedPeriod_DisplayText1" name="HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.DisplayText" type="hidden" value="pariodeB" />
```

In this case only the property `Id` associated with the radio button is binded.
How to bind the others?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Never hard code you html. Always use the string typed `HtmlHelper` methods to give you 2-way model binding (plus client side validation etc). And wh do you have 2 inputs for the `Selected`, `PickerFormat`, and `DisplayText` properties of  `SelectedPeriod` (only the first ones will be bound). And what is your `AllPeriodes` property for (you never use it in the view)

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why It doesn't work with the Html helpers. I have 2 selected because it's a radio button group. `AllPeriods` is a list of  `PeriodViewModel` to create the option button group.

Comment: It does work is you do it correctly. But its not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Of course I think It should work, but at this time I have no answer to the question mentioned in the link. I've searched all the day, tried a lot of things and I must go forward...

Comment: But no where in your other question do you create form controls for `Selected` etc (which would be `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HistoricViewModel.SelectedPeriod.Selected)` etc

Comment: Of course, in the foreach loop.

Comment: You cannot do it in a `foreach` loop. And in any case you are binding to the `SelectedPeriod` property and its a single object, not a collection so a loop makes no sense